# How to read a file and send that data to a csv file?

Tags: powershell, csv, export

What i am trying to do is to read a .dat file (or .txt), just the first line, and then that information export it to a csv file.

Everything goes OK except that it doesn't send the data i just read, it sends other stuff like lenght or attributes of the info itself.

Here's the code i have:

```
$a = Get-content C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Batchtutorial\text.dat -totalcount 1  
$a | export-csv "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Batchtutorial\newcsv.csv"
```

If i display the variable $a it shows me the information from the first line of the file, when the export happens is when another data or attributes from the data go to the csv file instead.

However here's the information that's being generated:

'#'TYPE System.String
PSPath  PSParentPath    PSChildName PSDrive PSProvider  ReadCount   Length
C:\Users\ralcanta\Documents\Batchtutorial\141005_150210ReconciledTravelCurrentPeriod.dat    C:\Users\ralcanta\Documents\Batchtutorial   141005_150210ReconciledTravelCurrentPeriod.dat  C   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem    1   190

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object into the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, the object's properties are exported as the fields of the output CSV. If you want just the first line of the input file written to the CSV you're better off using the `Out-File` cmdlet instead:

```
Get-Content 'C:\your\input.txt' -TotalCount 1 | Out-File 'C:\your\output.csv'
```

Comment: Add-Content might also be a good idea if the OP is looking to append. `-Append` on `Out-File` would also suffice